# Rust removal with electrolysis

Tags: rust

There are a lot of questions involving rust removal by electrolysis.  I have done it before and want to do it again.  The problem is I don't have any washing soda.  What other chemicals can I use?  I do have baking soda, Oxi Clean, borax, sodium hydroxide, and salt.  Will any produce byproducts that I should be concerned about?  (I know sodium hydroxide is caustic.)

Comment: I know this is one of those things that intersects with woodworking, but it is not strictly on topic for WW SE. That being said, you can research online easily for turning sodium bicarbonate (baking soda) into sodium carbonate ("washing soda") using your oven. I don't know if baking soda will work as-is. But my guess is that this is probably off-topic for WW.SW.

Comment: More to the point I'm pretty sure borax _is_ washing soda in some locales, and works the same way for electrolysis.

Comment: I know we're not supposed to do this but come on Rob, you could have Googled this in like 20 or 30 seconds! I know because I've researched the subject repeatedly over the years and I know what's out there.

Comment: @jdv, borax should be borax. Washing soda on the other hand may contain some borax, while being predominantly sodium carbonate which is what "washing soda" would generally be understood to be.

Comment: Honestly, I know we are tired of seeing youtubers shill for Evapo-Rust, but the product is so effective, and so easy to use, and so cheap in material and time in the long run that I'm going to just say: order some Evapo-Rust from Amazon and wait the week and it'll still be worth it.

Comment: Let me just say that I did search for the answer but the answer is always washing soda (sodium carbonate) and didn't know why.  For those of us that keep old tools I didn't think it was too off topic.  Thank you for your replies.

Comment: @jdv, yeah I'm certainly tired of seeing YouTubers shill it :-D But seriously, in the long term, and for larger pieces, there's no cost comparison with electrolysis (and I say that as someone who isn't a fan of it). Molasses soaks are also an extremely viable alternative for large volumes over a long time.

Comment: *"but the answer is always washing soda (sodium carbonate) and didn't know why"* cheap, widely available (in most places), does the job better than sodium bicarb, that may pretty much cover it. Sorry if my previous reply came across as overly harsh, but like I say the answer *is* out there, e.g. [here](https://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/general/effective-electrolytic-rust-removal-212426/) and [here](http://fergusontractors.org/nfs/wp-content/uploads/technical-articles/Rust-Removal-with-a-Battery-Charger.pdf). Additionally, you can go the opposite direction for your addition and use vinegar.

Comment: @Graphus there's a youtuber that built, I kid you not, the largest Evapo-Rust soak tub I've ever seen. It is spectacular. As a hand-tool guy, I can get by with a modest tub, and the occasional use of the goopy style for larger things I can't soak.

Comment: @jdv, large enough to soak the front end of a Model T? If not then I'm not impressed :-D

Comment: @Graphus, pretty close: https://youtu.be/z4LmhPE4seM

Comment: I recommend plain old Naval jelly. Bit messy but does a great job for me on firearm parts.